# What is this operator: &=

Tags: javascript, operators, bit-manipulation

Can someone explain what is the operator `&=` for?

I searched, but I got only results with `&` or `=`.

Comment: is this a regular operator? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: In general, a #= b is equivalent to a = a # b, for any binary operator #.

Comment: (Please note that accepted answer is incomplete. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8910652/1018783 for a more exhaustive explanation about the `&=` operator)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
a &= b;
```

Is the same as

```
a = a & b;
```

& is the "bitwise and operator", search for that.

Comment: More specifically, it's the "bitwise AND assignment operator" ([according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/a9h8y72a(v=vs.94).aspx), anyway).

Comment: Note that `&=` is the compound assignment operator for **both** the **bitwise** and the **logical** AND operators, not just the "bitwise and operator". Only peculiarity in the logical AND case is that the collapsed `&=` does not short-circuit (right hand operand is evaluated always), while the uncollapsed `&&` operator does short-circuit if the left hand operand evaluates as `false`.

Answer (score 7):

It's a shorthand operator which allows you to collapse

```
a = a & b
```

into

```
a &= b
```

Apart from bitwise operations on integers, `&=` can be used on boolean values as well, allowing you to collapse

```
a = a && b
```

into

```
a &= b
```

However, in the case of logical operation, the expanded form is short-circuiting, while the latter collapsed form does not short-circuit.

Example:

let `b()` be a function that returns a value and also does stuff that affects the program's state

let `a` be a boolean that is `false`

if you do

```
a = a && b()
```

the short-circuit happens: since `a` is `false` there's no need to evaluate `b` (and the extra computation that might happen inside `b()` is skipped).

On the other hand, if you do

```
a &= b()
```

the short-circuit doesn't happen: `b` is evaluated in any case, even when `a` is `false` (and evaluating `b()` wouldn't change the logical outcome), thus any extra computation that might happen inside `b()` does get executed.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
x &= y;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x & y;
```

Note that `&` is the bitwise and operator.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly it biwise operation...for example it can be used with [Flags]Enum.
It check if your flag variable has specific value.

Answer (score 0):

In C#(and in most languages I think) its the bitwise assigment operator.

a &= b is equivalent of a = a & b

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`a &= b` is equivalent to `a = a & b`